# Maximum value from a range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to find the highest value from a range and paste that value in a cell. I need to start from H5 and go down to the last value (length varies). So far I have been using this code:

```
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Log")


PressureMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("H5:H" & LastRow))

Sheets("Info").Select
Range("E4").Select
Selection.Formula = PressureMax

End With
```

However the highest value it returns is always 0. The "LastRow" is:

```
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Log")

LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
```

Would this be my problem, but it has worked else where in my code for other things?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to answer my own question with this code:

```
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Log")
Dim rng As Range
Dim pressuremax As Double

Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Log").Range("H5:H" & LastRow)

pressuremax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)

Sheets("Info").Select
Range("E4").Select
Selection.Formula = pressuremax
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  Only things I'd change: remove the With statement - you're not using it in the example and the last four lines of code could be condensed to `Sheets("Info").Range("E4") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)`

Comment: also, get rid of that select stuff.  Just use Sheets("Info").Range("E4").Formula = pressuremax